# Convert LINQ query to php mongodb query format

Tags: php, linq, mongodb

I'm using the official C# mongodb driver, and it does have LINQ support. But I'm having trouble trying to convert this to use the php driver.

This is the LINQ query:

```
.Where(c => DateTime.UtcNow.Subtract(c.DateRequested).TotalDays <= 14).Where(d => ((d.itemid == req.itemid) && (d.MediaType == req.MediaType)) && (d.Status != RequestStatus.Cancelled))
```

I'm not 100% sure how if I'm going about this correctly but this is my attempt so far in readable format:

```
Array
(
   [$and] => Array
       (
           [DateRequested] => Array
               (
                   [$gt] => MongoDate Object
                       (
                           [sec] => 1341754027
                           [usec] => 0
                       )

                   [$lte] => MongoDate Object
                       (
                           [sec] => 1342963627
                           [usec] => 0
                       )

               )

           [$and] => Array
               (
                   [$and] => Array
                       (
                           [itemid] => 76510
                           [MediaType] => 0
                       )

                   [Account] => Josh
               )

           [Status] => Array
               (
                   [$ne] => 3
               )

       )

)
```

And here is the messy form:

```
array('$and' => array('DateRequested' => array('$gt' => new MongoDate((time() - 1209600)), '$lte' =>new MongoDate(time())),'$and' => array('$and' => array('itemid' => $itemid,'MediaType' => $source),'Account' => $account),'Status' => array('$ne' => 3)))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure if I've inferred your correct document structure from the code examples above, but assuming a test document added in the `mongo` shell similar to:

```
// Insert test data
db.mycoll.insert({
    'DateRequested': new Date(),
    'itemid': 76510,
    'MediaType': 0,
    'Account': 'Josh',
    'Status': 2
});
```

An example search in PHP might look like:

```
<?php
    $DAYS14 = 14 * 24 * 60 * 60; // Seconds in 14 days
    $CANCELLED = 3; // Status

    // Dummy search data
    $data['itemid']    = 76510;
    $data['mediatype'] = 0;
    $data['account']   = 'Josh';

    $query = array(
        '$and' => array(
            array('DateRequested' => array('$lt' => new MongoDate(time()))),
            array('DateRequested' => array('$gte' => new MongoDate(time() - $DAYS14))),
        ),
        'itemid'    => $data['itemid'],
        'MediaType' => $data['mediatype'],
        'Account'   => $data['account'],
        'Status'    => array('$ne' => $CANCELLED),
    );

    $document = $collection->findOne($query);

    // Peek at the result
    print_r($document);
?>
```

Note that the query elements are implicitly using "and" criteria.  Where the same field needs to be repeated (eg. `DateRequested`), an explicit `$and` is required so the field keys are distinct.

Comment: Thanks. I wasn't aware that it used "and" implicitly like that.

Extra points for answering a tumbleweed question!